# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'InnerNativeModule.installCoreFunctions')

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

my react-native project was running, but today i tired to run it on andorid it gived the the abouve Error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'InnerNativeModule.installCoreFunctions')`. tried alot of thing `gradlew clean` `node modules deleted` `cache-clear` but no thing works

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hello Here is the solution.
go to `android/app/build.gradle` and search for the line

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

change this to

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

and in **MainApplication.java** file add these two line to the top

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;
```

and add this function

```
@Override
protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() { 
      return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); 
    }
```

Here is the screen shot[image]

in the **bable.config.js** file add these ,lines like this

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
  ],
};
```

and **index.js**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

After this clean your project, uninstall from the device and build it again.
Cheers!!

Comment: No. This solution results in
`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

Answer (score 9):

Step 1:- go to **android/app/build.gradle**

```
project.ext.react = [enableHermes: false,] // update here true
```

Step 2:- go to **android/app/src/main/java[Your Packages]/MainApplication.java**

```
    import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
    import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;
    
private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
...
    @Override
    protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() { 
          return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); 
        }
};
```

Step 3:- go to **bable.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],   //add this line
};
```

Step 4:- go to **index.js**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

Step 5:- paste this command on **Terminal**

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Step 6:- clean **gradlew** , delete ***build*** file under **android/app** and **uninstall** app from the devices

Step 7:- run your project