# react-navigation drawer - white screen issue / build failing on native 0.67.3

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Build:

"dependencies": {

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.1.2",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1"
```

},

"devDependencies": {

```
"@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
"babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
"eslint": "7.14.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
"react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
```

},

"jest": {

```
"preset": "react-native"
```

}

Hi All,

I'm trying to get the drawer navigation working on my project. I've created a fresh project via npx to make sure it wasn't any package conflicts but I end up with the same white screen on my android emulator.

I've installed the all dependencies mentioned on the below:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#installation

I read that it could be to do with alignItems set to central but I haven't got that set anywhere on this new project.

The only warning I get in debugger is 'Seems like you're using an old API with gesture components, check out new Gestures system!'. The project builds without any other errors.

Can anyone advise if they're experiencing the same issue?

Thanks :)

EDIT:

I've got it working on react-native version 0.63.0 but I don't want to downgrade my live project to get this working.

Even on 0.63.0 it wasn't plug and play I had to follow the below resources to get past the errors.

[react-native-safe-area-context throw `Unresolved reference:` error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378027/react-native-safe-area-context-throw-unresolved-reference-error)

[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'InnerNativeModule.installCoreFunctions')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70968067/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-innernativemodule-installcore)

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2746

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to get it working, it's literally the same fix as what I did on 0.63.0.

Follow the answer on this page:

[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'InnerNativeModule.installCoreFunctions')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70968067/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-innernativemodule-installcore)

Run:

**yarn add @babel/preset-typescript**

Just for the record here is what my dependencies look like when successfully working:

"dependencies": {

```
"@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.1",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.3",
"react-native-azure-auth": "^1.8.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.1.2",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1"
```

},
"devDependencies": {

```
"@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
"babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
"eslint": "7.14.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
"react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
```

},